# Converting a modal dialog window to pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I'm trying to convert a modal dialog with 3 DataTables to pdf using iTextSharp:

```
DataTable dtTable = (DataTable)ViewState["LoanPlan"];
DataTable dtTax = (DataTable)ViewState["PlanTaxData"];
DataTable dtPlan = (DataTable)ViewState["PlanAllData"];
```

I'm using this code to try and accomplish it:

```
protected void buttonPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    this.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
```

But it seems that it's actually trying to convert the whole .aspx page to .pdf format. How should I go about targeting just the modal dialogue or just the 3 DataTables?

Comment: what type is `this` in `this.RenderControl()`? do you mean a modal dialog extender, or a window.showModalDialog()?

Comment: It's a window.showModalDialog() type.

Comment: and buttonPDF is a control on that dialog, which itself should not be included on the PDF? I would look into the control hierarchy and perhaps not have `this.RenderControl(hw)` but something like `DataTableX.RenderControl(hw)` instead. Or make a panel that contains all you want to convert and do `PanelX.RenderControl(hw)`...

Comment: I'll give it a try. And update once I figure out the hierarchy.

Comment: Additionally, please don't use `HTMLWorker` when you can use `XMLWorker`. The former is a more limited version of the latter